# Cucumber step definition not working with | (pipe symbol) when using with cypress and Cucumber

Tags: cucumber, cypress

Has anyone tried using |(pipe symbol) in step definitions in Cypress?

I wrote step definition like this

```
Then ('I can see that the product (displayed|not displayed)',(isDisplayed) =>{
//My code here

})
```

But cypress throwing error that

```
Step implementation missing for: I can see that the product displayed 

node_modules/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/lib/resolveStepDefinition.js:211:1
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without `(` & `)` ?

i.e,

```
Then('I can see that the product displayed|not displayed',(isDisplayed) =>{
//My code here

})
```